# In FreeBSD, how do you send a mail message from a user on one server to a user on a different server?

Tags: freebsd, email, sendmail

The environment is FreeBSD 10.2 with default services including sendmail.

Sending a message from one user to another on the system works fine:

```
mail -s "A message" userb
Hi b, this is a.
CTRL-D
```

Which results in:

```
su - userb
you have mail
```

but, how do you send a message to another server in the network (not hosted on the internet)? e.g.

```
mail -s "A message" userb@anotherhost
mail -s "A message" userb@[192.168.14.13]
```

The remote hosts are configured and working individually as described for the local host above, but the commands don't seem to work for sending to another host. It doesn't error out, but no mail shows up on the other server.

```
running mail -v -s "A message" userb@[192.168.14.13]
```

results in:

```
250 2.0.0 t9VKPqha007199 Message accepted for delivery userb@remote...
Sent (t9VKPqha007199 Message accepted for delivery) 
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1] >>> QUIT 221 2.0.0 
myhost closing connection
```

mailq shows:

```
t9VKOKhl007191 (Permission denied)
```

Comment: If you type `mailq`, does it show anything in the queue?

Comment: What do the log files say? What happens when you include the `-v` flag on your `mail` command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I see: `t9VKOKhl007191 (Permission denied)`

Comment: @roaima - I see: `250 2.0.0 t9VKPqha007199 Message accepted for delivery
userb@remote... Sent (t9VKPqha007199 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 myhost closing connection`

Comment: Do you know whether any of the steps in the [FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/mail.html) for setting up mail have been done? If you don't do any setup, sendmail only listens for mail on `localhost` and won't listen for connections from other systems.

Comment: @willsenn please [edit] your question to include this information. For starters you can format it. Going onwards it stops the information being lost in a stream of comments.

Comment: @roaima as suggested, edited question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I did not realize this. I am off to read the handbook section.